# Given pmf of $X$, how $P(X\text{ is even})$ using R?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

I have a pmf of $X$, which is $X\sim \text{Bin}(n=20, p=0.2)$. I want to figure out how to calculate using `R` $P(X \text{ is even})$. This is what I figured out, by hand you would basically sum all even of $X$. Is the only way in `R` to do this is by summing `dbinom(x=i,size=20,prob=0.2)` where is `i` is an even number in `range(0,20)`? There must be a clever way?

Comment: you could use a vector calculation such as

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> i = seq(0, 20, by = 2)
> sum(dbinom(i, 20, .2))
[1] 0.5000183
```

You might want to look at the documentation, [`?seq`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/seq.html).

---

You could also do

```
> sum(dbinom(2*(0:10), 20, .2))
[1] 0.5000183
```

Comment: Last time I checked, $X = 0$ is an even outcome, so you would need to begin the count at $0$ instead.

Comment: @heropup I never checked. Hehe. Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes I still feel like I need to check because it seems odd!

Comment: @probablyme what does this do 2*(0:10)?

Comment: @TeodoricoLevoff  
`> 0:10`  
 `[1]  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10`  
`> 2*(0:10)`  
 `[1]  0  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20`

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of completeness (as this is a mathematics site and not a programming site), given $X \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n,p)$, let $E$ represent the event that $X$ is even.  Then $$\Pr[E] = \sum_{x=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \binom{n}{2x} p^{2x} (1-p)^{n-2x}.$$  To evaluate this sum, it is helpful to recall that $$(a+b)^n = \sum_{x=0}^n \binom{n}{x} a^{n-x} b^x,$$ so that $$(a+b)^n + (a-b)^n = \sum_{x=0}^n \binom{n}{x} (a^{n-x} b^x + a^{n-x} (-b)^x) = \sum_{x=0}^n \binom{n}{x} a^{n-x} b^x (1 + (-1)^x).$$  But notice that the expression $$1 + (-1)^x = \begin{cases} 2, & x \text{ is even} \\ 0, & x \text{ is odd}. \end{cases}$$  So it follows that $$(a+b)^n + (a-b)^n = 2 \sum_{x=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \binom{n}{2x} a^{n-2x} b^{2x},$$ and the choice $a = 1-p$, $b = p$ gives $$\Pr[E] = \frac{1}{2}(((1-p)+p)^n + ((1-p)-p)^n) = \frac{1 + (1-2p)^n}{2},$$ for $p \in [0,1].$

---

As for the specific case provided in the question, $n = 20$ and $p = 1/5$, the exact probability should be $$\frac{47685459212513}{95367431640625} = 0.50001828079220031488.$$

Comment: Complete indeed! :)

Answer (score 0):

you could use a vector calculation such as , 
even<- seq(2,20,by=2); 
sum(dbinom(x=even, size=20, prob=0.2)); 
R is working best for vector type calculation. In this way you can avoid by adding 10 times individually. Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

If the probability that you have an even number of successes after $n$ attempts is $e_n$ then $e_0=1$ and $$e_n=(1-p) e_{n-1} + p(1-e_{n-1})$$
which you can rewrite as $e_n=(1-2p) e_{n-1} + p$ and $e_n-\frac12 = (1-2p) (e_{n-1}-\frac12)$ giving a general result of $$e_n=\frac12+ \frac12(1-2p)^n$$ 
which when $n=20$ and $p=0.2$ gives $e_{20} = 0.5+0.5\times 0.6^{20} \approx 0.500018281$